# Get rows n index prior to all the rows that meet the criteria

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, candlestick-chart

I have written a program that find specific candlestick patterns based on a stock's day data (open, high, low, close) using pandas. Now I want to see what is the average price change one, two, or three days after a pattern appears. How could I get the rows after a pattern? Say I want all rows with a hammer candle I can get them like this.

```
data[data['Hammer'] == True]
```

```
    Symbol  Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Day Close   Hammer
4   AMZN    2019-12-16  1767.00 1769.50 1757.05 1769.21 3149300    Up        True
10  AMZN    2019-12-06  1751.20 1754.40 1740.13 1751.60 3119900    Up        True
41  AMZN    2019-10-23  1761.30 1770.05 1742.00 1762.17 2190300    Up        True
55  AMZN    2019-10-03  1713.00 1725.00 1685.06 1724.42 3624300    Up        True
66  AMZN    2019-09-18  1817.04 1822.06 1795.50 1817.46 2536000    Up        True
82  AMZN    2019-08-26  1766.91 1770.00 1743.51 1768.87 3085300    Up        True
```

Then I want the rows prior (the day after) in order to compare the closing price of that day to the previous day (Hammer day), how could I get shift to give me the actual row before the hammer when that row will most likely not meet the criteria? If I do something like

```
data.loc[data['Hammer'] == True]['Close'].shift()
```

I end up with the close from the next hammer, not the row directly after the hammer which is what I need.
Essentially I need the rows one index prior to all the rows that meet the criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, if anybody runs into a similar issue here is what I did. 
To get the row before or after the filter (hammer == True) shift must be applied before the filter.

```
data.shift()[data['Hammer'] == True]
```

For my particular situation, the following code solved the issue of grabbing the 'Close' column from the day after a hammer candle and putting it in a column for future comparison.

```
data['One Day After Hammer'] = data.shift()[data['Hammer'] == True]['Close']
```